# Route to controller without an action or ID in the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes, and 2 controllers "Home", "Properties":

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultWithNoActionInUrl",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

These urls route correctly and take me to the index actions:

- /
- /Home
- /Home/Index
- /Home/1
- /Properties/Index
- /Properties/1

This one keeps giving resource not found errror:

- /Properties

It seems like when I use the properties url with no action and ID, it does not map to either route.

What am I doing wrong with my route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may notice in the solution explorer, there is a folder by name "Properties", which contains AssemblyInfo.cs. 
If I am right here, when you write /Properties, it basically is captured by a module which is responsible for listing static files (without being routed to the asp.net mvc routing).And when it tries to list the contents of this folder the runtime disallows it as this folder is not configured for directory listing.

Similarly if you create a controller named "Content", you would see same error.

If it a possibility for you to change name of your controller?

If that's not a possibility you can following.

In your RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

For more information on how above works please see https://prerakkaushik.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/routing-request-for-static-files-with-or-without-extension-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Exactly what it was. I have never come across this before. Thanks for the link. I tried setting RouteExistingFiles to true, but then all the js and css file references return a 404. So I went with renaming the controller.

Comment: I think for you case just having routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; should be enough. Please let me know if that works for you. thanks

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned it caused my js and css files to not load, so I had to add these lines into the route config so my static resource could still load.             routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*wildcard}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*wildcard}");
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;